# Indicate operator-pending mode in vim-airline

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

I am using airline with basic settings. 
Is there a way to indicate operator-pending mode in the airline status line? In regular, vim default statusline (`:set statusline`) there is always displayed first letter of a command, whenever vim enters operator-pending mode. I'll be absolutely sufficient for me, but I don't know how should I modify this airline plugin.

Comment: Try Airline's issue tracker if you can't find that info in the plugin's documentation.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is probably not in airline, but

`set showcmd`

in your .vimrc

Comment: yes, this allows me to display first part of the command, so that's exactly what I need. But I was wondering how you can put it ON the airline statusline, for example near mode indicator.